# Highchart Event not firing in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts, ionic-framework

I am trying a run highchart line chart which is not firing event written in JS. This chart gets displayed inside Ionic Android Simulator. I have added couple of console logs to show where my code is working where it is not. Any thoughts on how to fix this? Here i am trying to mimic a real time chart by generating live data for the map series. I am using Jquery here not sure whether angular causing the issue.

Here is my code

```js
$scope.chartConfig4= {  chart: {
                type: 'spline',
                animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
                marginRight: 10,
                events: {
                    load: function () {
console.log("This is not getting logged!");

                        // set up the updating of the chart each second
                        var series = this.series[0];
                        setInterval(function () {
                            var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                                y = Math.random();
                            series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                        }, 1000);
                    }
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: null
            },
            xAxis: {
            title: {
                    text: 'UTC Time'
                },
                type: 'datetime',
                tickPixelInterval: 150
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Users (In Thousands)'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                        Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>' +
                        Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            exporting: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Users',
                data: (function () {
                
                
                    // generate an array of random data
                    var data = [],
                        time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                        i;
console.log("This works fine!");
                    for (i = -19; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                        data.push({
                            x: time + i * 1000,
                            y: Math.random()
                        });
                    }
                    return data;
                }())
            }]}
```

```html
 <div ng-controller="starter">
    <highchart id="chart4" config="chartConfig4" ></highchart>
</div>
```

The problem is when i display this as angular directive using highcharts-ng the real time mimic does not work.The chart displays without live realtime minic.

Comment: can you please share a fiddle for same?

Comment: Have a look at this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kskr5ebr/

Comment: The problem is when i display this as angular directive using highcharts-ng.

Comment: Do you observe any errors in the console (developer tools) ? Probably you have error with setInterval (missing in angular), so you should use $interval

Comment: I changed that. But checking on console load event did not get fired. It works fine in jquery. But dynamic chart does not work in highcharts-ng directive. This is what i am trying to convert to a angularjs using highcharts-ng http://tutorialspoint.com/highcharts/highcharts_dynamic_spline.htm

Comment: It looks like known bug reported on github. Ref: https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng/issues/203